# How to check if file exist on remote machine by scp in loop

Tags: loops, ssh, scp

How To loop this code:

```bsh
if scp remote-host:~/myfile ./ >& /dev/null
then 
    echo "transfer OK"
else 
    sleep 20
fi
```

loop must every 20 sec check for file on remote host, if file appear loop have to exit.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
while true
    if scp remote-host:~/myfile ./ >&/dev/null;
      then echo "transfer OK"; 
    fi
    sleep 20;
done
```

Answer (score 1):

```bsh
while true
do
    if scp remote-host:~/myfile . &> /dev/nul
    then
        echo "transfer OK"
        break
    fi
    sleep 30
done
```

Or, if you prefer something more compact:

```bsh
while :; do 
    (scp remote-host:~/myfile . &> /dev/null) && break
    sleep 30
done
echo "transfer OK"
```

Note that `:` is a built-in null command with a zero (success) exit code.